# Add an AppleScript commands for a scriptable application

Tags: objective-c, scripting, applescript

Is there any way to add additional AppleScript command, other than those listed in its documentation, to a scriptable application in mac os?
    There are many events that application has but the script command for them is not listed. Is there any other way to send those commands to scriptable application?
    I found ScriptingBridge framework, but it seems framework is only an objc wrapper to apple script.

Answer (score 0):

No, to do this you would have to change the code of the application and of course you can't do that. How an application responds to applescript commands is hard-coded into the program. However there is another approach. You could use gui scripting which means you can simulate mouse clicks and stuff on menu items, buttons etc. which may give you the ability to applescript what you need. Without more info about your specific task it's hard to give a solid suggestion though.

Comment: thanks regulus for answer, I want to automate itunes file sharing option, which is available when we add UIFileSharingEnabled flag. I want to automate the drag-n-drop functionality of putting my files in my app through iTunes.